# Gnome Settings - gsettings vs gconftool-2

Tags: gnome, desktop, icons, gnome3, desktop-icons

In GNOME 3 desktop icons are hidden by default. I tried to show them up this way:

```
 gconftool-2 --set -t bool /org/gnome/desktop/background/show-desktop-icons true
```

It didn't work. So I tried:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
```

It works!

`gconftool-2 --get /org/gnome/desktop/background/show-desktop-icons` says that value isn't set for this key.

`gconf-editor` does not list `/org` folder. Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GSettings API in GNOME 3 uses the `dconf` storage backend by default. (It *had* a GConf backend for a short while, but that didn't last.)

To access data in the database directly, use the `dconf` tool:

```
dconf list /org/gnome/
dconf dump /org/gnome/ > backup.ini
```

However, avoid doing this for anything else but backups. Most of the time, you'll want to use the high-level `gsettings` tool, which uses the same high-level API – so it'll always see the same settings the actual apps do, and verifies values against the same schema (which `dconf` *does not*).

```
gsettings list-schemas
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.background
```

`gsettings` is also backend-independent, so it would work the same on OS X (which uses a plist backend) and Windows (which uses a Registry backend).